# Unable to call save on entity within generic class

Tags: java, generics, service, dao

```
public class JobAssetService extends GenericService<JobAssetService, JobAsset, JobAssetDao> {

}
```

I'm trying to provide generic save() functionality to my service layer but it doesn't seem to like what I'm passing to `dao.save()`.  This seems like this should work...

Incompatible Types
Required: M
Found: java.lang.object

```
public class GenericService<T, M, Dao extends GenericDao> {

    protected Dao dao;
    protected EntityManager em;

    public GenericService() {

    }

    //map the dao/entity manager when instantiated
    public GenericService(Class<Dao> daoClass) {
        //map entity manager & dao
        //code removed for readability
    }

    public M save(M entity) {
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        entity = dao.save(entity); //IntelliJ complains about this
        tx.commit();

        return entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is code for Dao/GenericDao?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IntellijIDEA you can put your cursor on the error, then use ALT + ENTER and intellij will probably suggest you to cast the result of

```
dao.save(entity)
```

as "M"

```
entity = (M) dao.save(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should make `GenericDao` use generics too:

```
class GenericDao<M> {
    public M save(M entity) {
        ...
    }
}
```

then extend your generic service as follows:

```
public class GenericService<T, M, Dao extends GenericDao<M>> {
```

Comment: 'tis actually better than the answer that I had proposed. Only wanted to tips some intellij hacks as well.